# How can I solve this datatype problem with only one function,best with pattern matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm doing my Haskell Datentyp homework, and have try to solve this problem for a whole day.

The question is like this .

Use this Datentyp and only one function `tokenize`, other functions in the library are not permitted.

```
data Token = Text String
           | Placeholder String
             deriving (Eq, Show)

tokenize :: String -> [Token]
```

The brace is the sign of Placeholder

The result should like this:
when we give input`"Hallo {name}, {xyz}."`

should give `[Text "Hallo ", Placeholder "name", Text ", ", Placeholder "xyz", Text "."]` out

---

I have tried for a whole day, only Text output or Placehold is OK, but I have several problems:

1. How to handle curly brackets {}
2. How to use pattern match to match "{longtext...}"
3. Because of Datentype `[token]`,  `tokenize (x: xs) = x :[ Text (xs:[])]` do not works , so how to deal with it
4. how to combine the comma and all of them together, with only type `[token]` result function,I have tried ++ and : , but they all report error.
5. According to 4, there is a common question besides this homework: when using Datentype, and type of result doesn't fits type of input,  how to use recursion.

---

This is the last edition of my answer, it is still far away

```
data Token = Text String
           | Placeholder String
             deriving (Eq, Show)

tokenize :: String -> [Token]
tokenize [] = []
tokenize ('{':x:xs) = [ Placeholder (x:xs)]
tokenize (x: xs) = [ Text (x:xs)]
otherwise = error "TODO: Implementierung vervollstaendigen"
```

The result should like this:
when we give input`"Hallo {name}, {xyz}."`

should give `[Text "Hallo ", Placeholder "name", Text ", ", Placeholder "xyz", Text "."]` out

---

**Suppose all the input without internal bracket and are correctly denoted by curly brackets{}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the real-world, you'd probably want to use a library like Parsec. But for a homework, something like the following is probably enough:

```hs
data Token = Text String
           | Placeholder String
             deriving (Eq, Show)

tokenize :: String -> [Token]
tokenize xs = parseText "" xs

parseText :: String -> String -> [Token]
parseText text ('{':xs) = Text text : parsePlaceholder "" xs
parseText text (x:xs)   = parseText (text ++ [x]) xs
parseText text ""       = [Text text]

parsePlaceholder :: String -> String -> [Token]
parsePlaceholder name ('}':xs) = Placeholder name : parseText "" xs
parsePlaceholder name (x:xs)   = parsePlaceholder (name ++ [x]) xs
parsePlaceholder name ""       = [Text name]

main :: IO ()
main = print (tokenize "Hallo {name}, {xyz}.")
```

Instead of studying the code closely right away, you may want to try to copy only the type signatures of `parseText` and `parsePlaceholder` to see whether you can implement them yourself.

A few points of critique:

- Appending to the end of a linked list (as I do with `text ++ [x]` and `name ++ [x]`) is not very efficient. A possible approach would be to prepend (with `(:)`) and then in the end do once a `reverse`.
- `tokenize "{foo}"` returns `[Text "",Placeholder "foo",Text ""]`, which is not so nice, you may want to incorporate the following helper function:

  ```hs
  createText ""   = []
  createText text = [Text text]
  ```

Comment: You don't need to use `text ++ [x]` *or* `reverse` - it is quite possible to build the string in order as you consume it. You mainly need to switch away from accumulator style by removing the `name` parameter.

Comment: @amolloy "by removing the name parameter. " you mean as in your solution? Certainly that's what you'd do if this wasn't a small self-contained homework example. But then you would also just use parsec...

Comment: Yes. Doing it efficiently isn't any more difficult, or complicated, than the inefficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution, perhaps not efficient though. The general idea is to keep track of which tokens we've already parsed, which chars are to be added to the next `Text` token and what is left.

First we'll call a helper function named `tokenize'` (note the single quote at the end) which takes an additional param named `partial` that is a list of accumulated chars, which are partial `Text`-type `Token`.

When we encounter a '{' we scan the rest of the string to split on the first '}', create a `Placeholder` token and continue to process the rest of the string recursively. If we encounter any other char, we simply append it to `partial`.

Since it's a homework assignment, I've left the implementation of `splitPlaceholder` as an exercise.

```
tokenize :: String -> [Token]
tokenize str = tokenize' str  []

partialToText :: String -> [Token]
partialToText [] = []
partialToText xs = [Text xs] 

tokenize' :: String -> String -> [Token]
tokenize' [] partial  = partialToText partial
tokenize' ('{':xs) partial  = 
      let splitted = splitPlaceholder xs
          placeholderText = Placeholder (head splitted)
          rest = head $ tail splitted
          nextToken = partialToText partial
      in nextToken ++ (placeholderText : tokenize' rest [])
tokenize' (x:xs) partial = tokenize' xs (partial ++ [x])


    -- split input to two parts, first is everything till the first '}' (not including)
    -- and the second is the rest of the input string
    splitPlaceholder :: String -> [String]
    -- implementation left as an exercise
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we are writing a parser, we can benefit a great deal from using traditional parser techniques. The key point is that you want a `parse` function to parse only a part of the string at once, and so it is most convenient for it to return two things: the tokens parsed so far, and the *remainder* of the string: what's left to be parsed after handling those tokens.

So, our main recursive function will be

```
parse :: String -> (String, [Token])
```

This signature does not match the required signature of `tokenize`, but it is easy to write `tokenize` to delegate to it:

```
tokenize :: String -> [Token]
tokenize s = case parse s of
  ("", r) -> r
  (s, r) -> error ("unexpected text " ++ s)
```

Makes sense, right? If we parsed the stream and there's somehow text left, something went wrong; otherwise, the remainder is empty, so what's been parsed so far must be all of it.

`parse` itself is responsible for deciding, based on the first character it sees, whether to produce a Text or a Placeholder. In either case, it consumes the corresponding token, using `break` to identify the closing `}` (in the case of Placeholder), or the next opening `{` (in the case of Text). It conses the generated token onto the result of the recursive call to `parse`:

```
parse :: String -> (String, [Token])
parse "" = ("", [])
parse ('{':s) = let (name, ('}':s')) = break (== '}') s
                in (Placeholder name :) <$> parse s'
parse s = let (text, s') = break (== '{') s
          in (Text text :) <$> parse s'
```

Note that there is a hidden failure mode here, not exposed in the type signature: if the input contains a `{` character with no matching `}`, we will have a runtime error. But the signature of `tokenize` gives us little other choice: we have no way to indicate an invalid parse in the result type, so we can either lie by claiming there was a valid parse, or terminate the program abnormally; I prefer the latter.